# How to import Firefox data on Opera Snap?

Tags: firefox, snap, opera

I would like to import bookmarks and logins from Firefox into Opera, but this option isn't available, since it's using the snap version. Instead, it only allows to import from a bookmarks file. How would you enable this feature?